# How to make text start at space place on x-axis (different divs)

Tags: css

This may seem like a simple question and may have a simple solution but I was wondering how I can get two text elements (from a button) start at the space spot on the x-axis (they are two different divs). I am referring to the button's text in the image below.

[image]

How can I get both the text "Dashboard" and "A new button" to start at the same position on the x axis?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #ced4da;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

input[type="button"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: Transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 92%;

  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: regular;
  color: white;
}

.side-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  width: 17%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #272C32;
}

.sub-title {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
}

.sub-title h3 {
  color:  #B9B9B9;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.splitter {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;

  width: 85%;
  height: 0.5px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.button form i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.button input:hover+i {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="side-bar">
  <div class="sub-title">
    <h3>ADMIN TOOLS<h3>
  </div>
  <div class="splitter"></div>
  <div class="button">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Dashboard" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'"/>
      <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="A new button" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'"/>
      <i class="fas fa-hand-paper fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-bar"></div>
</div>
```

And if you have time, how does my CSS code look? I am still learning and would like some feedback too if you don't mind :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is put a `<div>` element around your `<form>` element ***s***, then set its position to wherever you want it, and its `text-align: left;`. BTW your CSS looks excellent, just keep in mind that some things can be simplified, e.g.

> - {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

This is very good, but `*` is the same as `body`, even though it's documented differently. `*` applies to all the content, but content is only displayed if it's in the `<body>` element.

Very good looking however, keep it up!

P.S. I'd vote you up if I could, but I'm out of votes - I'll do it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick, I got it working! And thank you so much for the feedback! It is really encouraging! :) Thank you so much again! :)

Comment: Not at all! Always glad to help.